# Update panel with Html code post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have html control dropdown with multiselection in Update panel. I want a post back on change or complete the multiselctio dropdown option.

```
<ContentTemplate>
   <table class="boxTable1" style="width: 100%;">
   <tr style="height: 5px;">
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <asp:Label ID="lblBPSIOU" runat="server" Text="BPS IOU"></asp:Label></td>
     <td>
     <select id="ddlroll" runat="server" multiple="true" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(this,'')"  class="multiselect-group">
       </select>
     </td>
<td>
     <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label></td>
      <td>
     <select id="ddlName" runat="server" multiple="true" onchange="ddl_OnChange(this);" class="multiselect-group">
                    </select>
                </td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I want a post back to fill name as per the roll number selection from database.

Pleas help.

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: For what purpose you are using HTML dropdown ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Triggers to the update panel like as below:

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlRoll" />
</Triggers>
```

here, control name is the dropdown that you have used. i.e., **ddlRoll**.

you can include this Trigger just before the opening of **ContentTemplate** tag.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It's not working..actually if ddlroll will be asp.net control then it will work otherwise it wont trigger postback..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UniqueID to postback.

```
<ContentTemplate>
   <table class="boxTable1" style="width: 100%;">
   <tr style="height: 5px;">
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <asp:Label ID="lblBPSIOU" runat="server" Text="BPS IOU"></asp:Label></td>
     <td>
     <select id="ddlroll" runat="server" multiple="true" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('<%= ddlroll.UniqueID %>','')"  class="multiselect-group">
       </select>
     </td>
<td>
     <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label></td>
      <td>
     <select id="ddlName" runat="server" multiple="true" onchange="ddl_OnChange(this);" class="multiselect-group">
                    </select>
                </td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
    </ContentTemplate>
```